# VBA to update pivot field

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I recorded this:

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Min Closed Mth")
        .PivotItems("2016-10").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("2017-11").Visible = True
    End With
```

Each month, I run this report as a running 13. This was ran this month. We subtract two months back and then add one month back. I hope that makes sense. Anyway, while this code works for December, it isn't any good going to each month forward. I also need to address that each January the year is different.

I've come up with this:

```
Sub Update_Pivots()

Dim thisMonth As Integer
Dim lastMonth As Integer
Dim thisYear As Integer

If Month(Date) = 1 Then
    thisYear = Year(Date) - 1
    thisMonth = Month(Date) - 1
    lastMonth = Month(Date) - 2
Else
    thisYear = Year(Date)
    thisMonth = Month(Date) - 1
    lastMonth = Month(Date) - 2
End If

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Min Closed Mth")
    .PivotItems("[thisYear].&[-]&.[lastMonth]").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("[thisYear].&[-]&.[thisMonth]").Visible = True
End With

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Min Closed Mth")
    .PivotItems("[thisYear].&[-]&.[lastMonth]").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("[thisYear].&[-]&.[thisMonth]").Visible = True
End With

End Sub
```

I get a run-time '1004 error
        Unable to get the PivotItems property of the PivotField class.

Nevermind that while the dates work for January, they don't for February because thisMonth and Year should be current but lastMonth and year should have previous year.

This is my first post. I've been doing a lot of simple stuff with VBA but now because of that, I'm being asked to do more.

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `DateAdd` to calculate the correct months, and then format that as `"yyyy-mm"`:

```
Sub Update_Pivots()

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Min Closed Mth")
        .PivotItems(Format(DateAdd("m", -14, Date),"yyyy-mm")).Visible = False
        .PivotItems(Format(DateAdd("m", -1, Date),"yyyy-mm")).Visible = True
    End With

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Min Closed Mth")
        .PivotItems(Format(DateAdd("m", -14, Date),"yyyy-mm")).Visible = False
        .PivotItems(Format(DateAdd("m", -1, Date),"yyyy-mm")).Visible = True
    End With

End Sub
```